# Automate the creation of a user in IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, ftp, iis-7.5

How can I automate the creation of a user in IIS7?

I'm using C#.  I have code that automates the creation of a website, and I found some examples for automating the creation of an FTP site.

I also need to automate the creation of a IIS user for each FTP site that I create.

I could possibly just edit the administration.config file, under        I could just add another element for each new user, but I wouldn't know how to set the password attribute, which is encoded.   Plus, there's gotta be an easier more reliable way to do this.

The FTP users that I need to set up are not associated with any website.  These users will only log into the FTP site, not into any website.

To manually add a user, I can run the feature "IIS Manager Users", then simply click on "Add User..."

This adds an entry to the config file, as I mentioned in my original post.

I then associate that user to my ftp site by adding an FTP Authorization Rule for that user.

As for my current configuration... On IIS7, under Management Service, under "Identity Credentials" I selected "Windows credentials or IIS Manager credentials".

Answer (score 2):

For adding the users to Administration.config you can use the API in Microsoft.Web.Management.dll  ManagementAuthentication.CreateUser, the following blog shows how to call it from POwerShell: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151005201351/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/carlosag/archive/2009/10/23/adding-iis-manager-users-and-permissions-through-powershell.aspx)

To add the FTP Authorization Rule you can use Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll. See: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.ftpServer/security/authorization for an example on how to do that.

Also consider using Configuration Editor to generate the code to automate changes to IIS configuration.
http://blogs.iis.net/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/01/11/tip-42-did-you-know-configurationeditor-allows-you-to-generate-c-javascript-or-appcmd-script-to-update-configuration.aspx

Comment: I tried using Microsoft.Web.Manager.dll but when I went to add the reference, I couldn't find that dll, which I would have expected to be in the framework... but I found it in the inetsrv directory, so I copied it to my project directory and added the reference.  (Something tells me that this isn't the correct way to add the reference).  Then, I called ManagementAuthentication.CreateUser() and got the following error:  The configuration section 'system.webServer/management/authentication' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Comment: Also, I was playing with the configuration editor, but it doesn't look like I have access to the administration.config file, like the example shows.

Comment: Indeed Configuration Editor does not expose Administration.config, but using Microsoft.Web.Management.dll which should be located in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\ is the best option, since it will suport custom providers (in case users are stored in SQL or some other storage).

Comment: When I use Microsoft.Web.Management.dll and call ManagementAuthentication.CreateUser(), On every machine I try it on, I'm still getting the error:  The configuration section 'system.webServer/management/authentication' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.   Any Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, there is a known issue when running this code in 32-bit processes in a 64-bit machine. If you are using Visual Studio, you will need to turn off the "enable visual Studio host process" checkbox under debugging, or just run it from a 64 bit process.

Comment: I got the admin code working, but how do I hash the password?  Leaving it unhashed doesn't work.  Using FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile with "MD5" or "sha1" doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use:

Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthentication.CreateUser(userName, password);

This method will encode the password for us.

Comment: Did you read my response above? That is exactly what I said 10 days ago.